# Malloc large space of struct and accessing it like arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, hash, malloc

I'm dealing with implementing a hash table. My understanding of a hashtable is that is that to have an array like table where you're able to access the elements quickly by getting the hash value and modding it by the table size. So my initial thought was declaring

```
Node *hTable [100];
```

where

```
typedef struct node {
    char *s; 
    int value;
} Node;
```

and going to the index of the array and malloc a new element that belongs there. But, the problem is that I need to grow my table.

So, my question is, how would I make a dynamic table, but access it like an array? (e.g `table[i]`).

I know that you need to call something like

```
Node *table = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)*size);
```

which lets you access it like a table `table[i] =...` but if I did that, I can't declare a new Node in the index of the table

```
table[i]=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Here's a code that I've been testing with (getting seg fault) to better give a view of the problem:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3
  4 typedef struct node {
  5         int data;
  6         struct node *next;
  7 } Node;
  8
  9
 10 void main() {
 11         Node **list;
 12         *list = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)*10);
 13         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 14                 list[i] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); //problem here?
 15                 list[i]->data = i;
 16                 list[i]->next = NULL;
 17         }
 18         printf("printing...\n");
 19         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 20                 printf("%d ", list[i]->data);
 21         }
 22 }
```

Comment: `Node **list; *list = ...` is already undefined behavior. `list` is uninitialized and you dereference it.

Comment: `list = malloc(sizeof(*list)*10);`

Comment: You can grow your table with `realloc()`. It's the same whether it's an array of `Node` or an array of `Node*`.

Comment: Please don't paste code with line numbers, it makes it hard for people to copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how you allocate space for `list`. `list` is uninitialized and does not point to valid memory, you must allocate space for it first, and then allocate space for each element:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;


int main() //return type of main is int
{
    Node **list;
    list = malloc(10 * sizeof *list); //allocate memory for list not *list, also no need to cast return value of malloc.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list[i] = malloc(sizeof *list[i]); //allocate space for each element.
        list[i]->data = i;
        list[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    printf("printing...\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", list[i]->data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain 10 * sizeof **list? how is it different from 10*sizeof(Node**)?

Comment: @user10416282 In this example `sizeof (Node)` and `sizeof *list` are equal, but if you change the type of `list` you also have to change it in the `malloc` parameter and if not could lead to bugs. Therefore I would prefer it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct node {
         int data;
         struct node *next;
 } Node;


 int main() {
         // just initialize it this way ( previous was undefined behavior, dereferencing an initialize pointer)
         Node **list= malloc(sizeof(Node*)*10);
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 list[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node*)); //problem here?
                 list[i]->data = i;
                 list[i]->next = NULL;
         }
         printf("printing...\n");
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 printf("%d ", list[i]->data);
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be an array of pointers, you can simply make an array of nodes, with:

```
Node *list = malloc(sizeof *list * count);
```

Then you can access `list[i].s` and `list[i].value`.

When you want to grow the table, you use `realloc()`:

```
new_list = realloc(list, sizeof *list * new_count);
if (new_list) {
    list = new_list;
} else {
    // report allocation failure
}
```